# Why does python have string.find but list.index?

Tags: python, language-design

Is there any documented reason why `list` has an `index` function, rather than using the more natural word `find` for both cases?

It seems like the kind of decision that might have an official paper trail in an email archive or USENET thread, but I can't find one.

Comment: `str` has an `index` method too.

Comment: This will largely be a matter of opinion and/or language heritage/history, but I don't see these functions as being the same. A `string.find()` locates a substring which does have a starting index, but spans a range of characters in a substring. `list.index()` on the other hand finds the single index corresponding to an element. That element is completely contained at that index. As @user2357112 points out, there is also a `string.index()` but it is functionally the same as `string.find()` except that it raises an exception on failure.

Comment: Probably the same reason C++ has both [`std::string::size` and `std::string::length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) the first is consistency with the other containers, the second is what would seem more natural in the context of a string

Comment: `list` has `index` and `str` has `find`, because they do different things. But then, `str` wants to behave like a `list`, so it also has `index`. On the other hand, `list` does not want to behave like a `str`, so it does not have `find`.